# Remove the HTTP Server header in Jetty 9

Tags: java, jetty

This is how you hide the server version in Jetty 8:

```
Server server = new Server(port);
server.setSendServerVersion(false);
```

How do you do it in Jetty 9? So now it should look something like this?

```
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.setSendServerVersion(false);
//TODO: Associate config with server???
Server server = new Server(port);
```

Comment: I know disabling sending the server version is not ideal, but I have a specific scenario where I can't avoid it for now.

Comment: Why is _sending the server version is not ideal_? I mean no client should use it in anyway and it may have security implications. In my opinion it should be disabled by default or am I missing something?

Comment: Server header is definitely used, it may affect your search ranking, and also is used to create technology/browser popularity graphs which are frequently used by certain types of people to make technology decisions.

Comment: Oh I see, for statistical purposes, yes that makes sense. However, why does it affect search ranking?

Comment: I know there isn't a lot of point in sending the server version, but it also doesn't really seem like there is much point in hiding it. The only argument I have seen is "for security", but wouldn't an attacker just try every known exploit, like they do for any other attack?

Comment: @Trejkaz If you just throw everything at the server and hope something sticks (while a valid plan), you have a better chance of tripping off a security suite than if you try a smaller subset of exploits based on known server version.

Comment: So what we're saying is that hiding the version is not the best approach, but returning a _misleading_ version might be effective? lol

Comment: This specific question is not about "how" to do it, not "why" do it. But that said, there are many reasons why. For example, one of the chief reasons you might want to do it, is that you work in an organisation where the "security team" forces you to do it (independently of your own personal assessment of the usefulness of doing it)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If worked out some code that seems to work. Not sure if its right, but at least it works (:

```
Server server = new Server(port);
for(Connector y : server.getConnectors()) {
    for(ConnectionFactory x  : y.getConnectionFactories()) {
        if(x instanceof HttpConnectionFactory) {
            ((HttpConnectionFactory)x).getHttpConfiguration().setSendServerVersion(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This only works before `server.start()` as the configuration is propagated to many other components during startup.  At which point changes to the Connectors no longer have an impact.

Answer (score 37):

In Jetty 9, you need to configure it on HttpConfiguration:

```
HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
httpConfig.setSendServerVersion( false );
HttpConnectionFactory httpFactory = new HttpConnectionFactory( httpConfig );
ServerConnector httpConnector = new ServerConnector( server,httpFactory );
server.setConnectors( new Connector[] { httpConnector } );
```

Comment: You should add the last step: `server.setConnectors(new Connector[] {httpConnector});`.

Comment: The important bit to set the port for the new connector is this: `httpConnector.setPort(port);`. Since the default connector is being replaced the port passed to the `Server` constructor is not used.

Answer (score 11):

If you use jetty9 as a standalone server you can disable the server signature by setting `jetty.httpConfig.sendServerVersion=false` in the file `start.ini`.

Answer (score 3):

Lambda-style variant of Jacob's solution (which worked for me):

```
final Server server = new Server(port);
Stream.of(server.getConnectors()).flatMap(connector -> connector.getConnectionFactories().stream())
            .filter(connFactory -> connFactory instanceof HttpConnectionFactory)
            .forEach(httpConnFactory -> ((HttpConnectionFactory)httpConnFactory).getHttpConfiguration().setSendServerVersion(false));
```

Comment: Also note, only works if used before `server.start()`.

Answer (score 2):

There is now an HttpConfiguration object with that setting on it.

org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration

Look to the jetty.xml for the section on http configuration section showing how to setup the object and then the jetty-http.xml file which shows how that configuration is used.  Remember that the jetty xml files are really just a thin skin over java and work basically the same.

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-server/src/main/config/etc/jetty.xml

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-server/src/main/config/etc/jetty-http.xml

Comment: I have seen this, but the problem is I'm not using a jetty xml file, Im starting Jetty embedded.

Comment: same thing, just translate it into the relevant java calls

Comment: I have reviewed the javadoc and googled it... The `HttpConfiguration` class has no documentation on how to use it.

Comment: the jetty.xml is nothing more then a thin smeer of xml over the java itself, it works in java exactly how it does in the xml...we will have to add an example to the embedded examples project I guess

Answer (score 1):

Some security analysis software will flag sending the server version in the response header as an issue.

OP was looking for solution for embedded, but if your Jetty deployment uses the server.ini file, you can simply set jetty.send.server.version=false

Answer (score 0):

in `jetty9.2`, change this config to `false` in `start.ini`

```
# should jetty send the server version header?
jetty.send.server.version=true
```