# Removing only the version number from Jetty's response header

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

[This answer explains how the server version header can be completely removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652902/remove-the-http-server-header-in-jetty-9) by using HttpConfiguration.setSendServerVersion(false).

Is there a way to preserve the header, removing only the version *number*?

I am using Jetty 9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. Perhaps the easiest (but not the cleanest) is to let Jetty send the default server header, but override the default version string to whatever you like right after you start the server:

```java
private Server startServer() {
    Server server = new Server();

    // ... configure connectors, whatever you like

    server.start();

    // and do this the important part: *after* server.start():
    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.setJettyVersion("Jetty");

    return server;
}
```

This way jetty sends `Server: Jetty` header, without version for each http based connectors (including https).
This works because Jetty prebuilds these kind of headers on server startup in a static array.

Comment: Note: this also adjusts the `X-Powered-By` header value as well.