# How to remove server version(Server: Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT)) from Spark web UI?

Tags: java, linux, apache-spark, ubuntu-16.04, embedded-jetty

I want to remove the server version being returned by the Spark web ui. I'm using Spark out of the box so the solutions I found elsewhere which refer to using either an `after` directive(https://github.com/perwendel/spark/issues/331#issuecomment-144521580) or programmatic solutions([Remove the HTTP Server header in Jetty 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652902/remove-the-http-server-header-in-jetty-9)) wouldn't work for this case.

I didn't find any configuration option in the documentation as well.

Answer (score 0):

I can remove this header with after directive and replace jetty version to empty string.

```
after((req, res) -> {
       res.header("Server", "");
       });
```

Why does not this directive work for you?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've updated the question. I saw this option mentioned in a related github issue page, but where(which file or directory) do I use this directive in?

Comment: In main of program. With after directive you capture all the calls you make to the server. Example,
```    
before("/*", (req, res) -> log.info("first call"));
get("/users", (req, res)->log.info("second call"));
after("/*", (req, res)->log.info("third call"));
```
http://sparkjava.com/documentation#routes